# When does localStorage get cleaned by the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Is `localStorage` cleaned  after I close my browser?

Comment: Thx to all i figured out why it was cleaned - bug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it should not be cleaned by default. It might get cleaned if you cleaned it manually. Also private/inkognito browsing cleans it after you close the browser.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not cleaned then (that would kind of defeat the point!).

...unless you're browsing in some sort of privacy mode, in which case the browser may clear it, this may vary by browser as to how it's implemented,and certainly will vary over time...since they all handle the "private mode" differently.

On the other hand if you *want* to clear it, there is a method: `localStorage.clear()`